# SwiftUI Dictionary - The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time

Tags: swift, dictionary, compiler-errors, swiftui

When I loop over a dictionary to get a value of a specific key I get this error but I don't know how to simplify it more.

Stored Dictionary

```
@Published var weekDayDictionary : [String : String] = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "weekDayDictionary") as? [String : String] ?? [:] {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.weekDayDictionary, forKey: "weekDayDictionary")
        }
    }
```

Function

```
func displayWeekDayTime(dictionary: [String: String], identifier: String) -> AnyView {
        var time = ""
        for (key, _) in dictionary {
            if key == identifier {
                time = dictionary[key]!
            }
        }
        return AnyView(Text(time))
    }
```

I have a String as Identifier and if that is equal to the key in the dictionary I want to get the value.

I also tried

```
func displayWeekDayTime(dictionary: [String: String], identifier: String) -> String {
        var time = ""
        time = dictionary[identifier]!
        return time
    }

Text(self.displayWeekDayTime(dictionary: self.customModifiers.weekDayDictionary, identifier: item.title))
```

Is there an easier way to get a value from a known key without getting this error?

Comment: not related to your question but why not simply `AnyView(Text(dictionary[identifier] ?? ""))` Looping all dictionary keys is definitely a no go.

Comment: Instead of returning `AnyView` it might be better to return `some View` and annotate the function with `@ViewBuilder`. And I'd recommend you split your code into parts. This error usually happens when you have huge amounts of view code in one function.

Comment: @Leo Dabus you’re right but still get the error.

Comment: @pawello2222 How to annotate the function with ViewBuilder?

Comment: Add `@ViewBuilder` in front of the function: `@ViewBuilder func displayWeekDayTime(...`

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
- otherwise it is just guessing.

Comment: still not working and I don't know how to solve it. I tried to make the code as simple as possible and I don't think it's heavy to read that particular data

Comment: @xmetal As suggested, create a *minimal, reproducible example* (preferably in a new project) - such that we can copy and reproduce the issue ourselves.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem just by closing the project, re open it and set the View as Leo Dabus said and worked...

Comment: @xmetal Glad to hear it. By breaking your code into smaller parts you may avoid similar problems in the future.